# My Website Bootstrap Columns (col-md-4) are over spilling in certain places and I cant seem to isolate the issue

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

[image: The Issue]

Ok so my issue which can be viewed on site [here](https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/our-story/news/) as well as seen on the attached image

Basically the issue is I'm using bootstrap with 3 columns and at certain points the 3 columns seems to overspill as seen in the attached photo and provided website link

I really do appreciate any help on this

Thanks

I'm not really sure why this is happening, Its something related to the heading underneath the image. If I set the display to none on the heading it seems to align just fine.

Due to requests here is the code sample hope its clear:

```php
  global $delay; // Each preview fades in after an incremental delay of 0.1s
  
  // If single post sidebars ...
  if(is_single()) :
    $col = '<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">';
    $small_title = ' style="font-size: 0.8em; text-align: left; margin-top: 0;"';
  else :
    $col = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
  endif;

  // if team archive (landing page) ...
  if (is_post_type_archive('team_pt')):
    // ... set figure to square
    $team_square = ' class="team-square-preview"';
    // and position in company. If not set, add a non-breaking space
    $position = (get_field('team_position')) ? '<h3>'.get_field('team_position').'</h3>' : '<h3>&nbsp;</h3>';
  endif;
?>

<?php echo $col; ?>
  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: <?php echo $delay; ?>s">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
              <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :?>
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-large'); ?>
              <?php else : ?>
                  <img class="logo-placeholder" src="<?php echo get_field('company_logo','option')['sizes']['medium_large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_field('company_logo','option')['alt']; ?>">
                  <?php if (is_post_type_archive('team_pt')): // Team member silhouette ?>
                    <img class="team-placeholder" src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/inspiration-marketing-theme/assets/images/team-member.png" alt="Novum team member">
                  <?php endif; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </figure>
          </div>
         <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
        <?php echo $position; // Only for team landing page ?>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php $delay = $delay+0.1; ?>
```

The outputted HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
            
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <nav class="project-categories-filter">
        <ul class="project-categories-menu">
          <li class="active"><a href="/our-story/news/" class="projects-button">All</a></li><li><a href="/category/covid-19/" class="projects-button">Covid 19 Updates</a></li><li><a href="/category/general-news/" class="projects-button">General News</a></li>        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>        <div class="row">
            <section class="entry-content">
                
                
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.1s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/novum-raises-over-e5000-for-st-francis-hospice/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="946" height="939" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice.jpg 946w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice-300x298.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice-150x150.jpg 150w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice-768x762.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice-600x596.jpg 600w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/St-Francis-Hospice-100x100.jpg 100w" sizes="(max-width: 946px) 100vw, 946px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Novum Raises over €5,000 for St. Francis Hospice</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.2s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/key-thought-provoking-insights-from-the-novum-store-of-the-future-webinar/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="1267" height="713" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Key-Thought.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Key-Thought.jpg 1267w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Key-Thought-300x169.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Key-Thought-1024x576.jpg 1024w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Key-Thought-768x432.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Key-Thought-600x338.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 1267px) 100vw, 1267px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Key Thought-Provoking Insights from the Novum Store of the Future Webinar</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.3s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/changing-global-food-trends-due-to-covid-19/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="1031" height="719" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Global-Food-Trends.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Global-Food-Trends.jpg 1031w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Global-Food-Trends-300x209.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Global-Food-Trends-1024x714.jpg 1024w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Global-Food-Trends-768x536.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Global-Food-Trends-600x418.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 1031px) 100vw, 1031px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Changing Global Food Trends due to Covid-19</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.4s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/grow-your-business-with-the-store-of-the-future-webinar/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="768" height="402" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success-300x157.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success-600x314.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Grow your business with the Store of the Future Webinar</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/the-3-main-pitfalls-of-traditional-refrigeration-systems/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="2560" height="1707" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-scaled.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-scaled.jpg 2560w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-300x200.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-1024x683.jpg 1024w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-768x512.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-1536x1024.jpg 1536w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-2048x1366.jpg 2048w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-1800x1200.jpg 1800w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Three-pit-falls-600x400.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 2560px) 100vw, 2560px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>The 3 Main Pitfalls of Traditional Refrigeration Systems</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.6s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/7-reasons-why-millennials-are-flocking-towards-frozen/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="2560" height="1707" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-scaled.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-scaled.jpg 2560w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-300x200.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-1024x683.jpg 1024w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-768x512.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-1536x1024.jpg 1536w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-2048x1365.jpg 2048w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-1800x1200.jpg 1800w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Seven-reasons-why-millenials-600x400.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 2560px) 100vw, 2560px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>7 Reasons why Millennials are flocking towards Frozen</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.7s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/emerging-frozen-food-trends-and-the-customer-of-the-future/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="835" height="230" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="Novum logo" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo.jpg 835w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-300x83.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-768x212.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-600x165.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 835px) 100vw, 835px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Emerging Frozen Food Trends and the Customer of the Future</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.8s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/interesting-and-emerging-uses-of-frozen-food/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="835" height="230" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="Novum logo" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo.jpg 835w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-300x83.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-768x212.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-600x165.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 835px) 100vw, 835px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Interesting and Emerging Uses of Frozen Food</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 0.9s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/the-health-credentials-of-frozen-food/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="2560" height="2513" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-scaled.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-scaled.jpg 2560w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-300x295.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-1024x1005.jpg 1024w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-768x754.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-1536x1508.jpg 1536w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-2048x2011.jpg 2048w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-1800x1767.jpg 1800w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Health-Credentials-600x589.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 2560px) 100vw, 2560px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>The Health Credentials of Frozen Food</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/domestic-freezers-drastically-increase-frozen-food-sales/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img class="logo-placeholder" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-768x212.jpg" alt="Novum logo">
                                            </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Domestic Freezers Drastically Increase Frozen Food Sales</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1.1s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/innovative-leap-technology-proves-itself-in-times-of-crisis/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img class="logo-placeholder" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-768x212.jpg" alt="Novum logo">
                                            </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Innovative LEAP™ Technology Proves Itself in Times of Crisis</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1.2s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/us-frozen-food-sales-soar/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="959" height="720" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Frozen-Food-Sales.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Frozen-Food-Sales.jpg 959w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Frozen-Food-Sales-300x225.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Frozen-Food-Sales-768x577.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Frozen-Food-Sales-600x450.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 959px) 100vw, 959px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>US Frozen Food Sales Soar</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1.3s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/what-is-the-leap-store-of-the-future/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="1424" height="522" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Leap-Store-of-the-Future.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Leap-Store-of-the-Future.jpg 1424w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Leap-Store-of-the-Future-300x110.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Leap-Store-of-the-Future-1024x375.jpg 1024w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Leap-Store-of-the-Future-768x282.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Leap-Store-of-the-Future-600x220.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 1424px) 100vw, 1424px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>What is the LEAP Store of the Future?</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1.4s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/going-global-for-growth-with-novum/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="800" height="533" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Going-Global-for-growth.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Going-Global-for-growth.jpg 800w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Going-Global-for-growth-300x200.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Going-Global-for-growth-768x512.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Going-Global-for-growth-600x400.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Going Global for Growth with Novum</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1.5s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/leap-store-of-the-future-a-huge-success/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="768" height="402" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success-300x157.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Store-of-the-Future-a-huge-success-600x314.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>LEAP Store of the Future a Huge Success</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  <div class="child-page-preview" style="animation-delay: 1.6s">
    <a href="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/important-update-from-novum/">
      <div class="title-tabs">
          <div class="child-page-img-container">
            <figure>
                                <img width="835" height="230" src="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo.jpg" class="attachment-medium-large size-medium-large wp-post-image" alt="Novum logo" srcset="https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo.jpg 835w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-300x83.jpg 300w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-768x212.jpg 768w, https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/novum-new-logo-600x165.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 835px) 100vw, 835px">                          </figure>
          </div>
         <h2>Important Update from Novum</h2>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
                
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It helps if you add samples of the code you're using.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. My guess is that you're putting more than 12 columns in a row, and the overflow isn't being cleared

Comment: Just updated it Jeff. Thanks

Comment: That is happening because some titles have two lines, which results in the columns having different heights. One solution would be to use a JS library for equal heights. Another better solution would be upgrading to Bootstrap 4. It uses Flexbox instead of Float and this issue does not happen.

Comment: @j08691. I just changed the posts per page to 9 and its still an issue https://wordpressmu-84115-1265955.cloudwaysapps.com/our-story/news/page/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should put every 3 `col-md-4` in `row` class, example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is being auto generated in a while loop in php as can be seen above

Comment: @Garath Then limit the post titles to fixed length to make them single line.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was to add a min-height to the col-md-12:

`html <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="min-height:325px;">`